# angularjs ui-router require

Tags: dynamic, requirejs, angular-ui-router

I have some trouble declaring my controller using ui.router and requirejs.
I'm trying calling route from a variable (menu) to create dynamic route.

See my code below
controller declaration:

```
var Portal = angular.module('Portal');
Portal.controller('SUSR',['$scope', function($scope)
{
    $scope.name = 'This my name';
}]);
```

this is my loader:

```
var menu = {
    'SUSR':
        ['ACTIVITY',
        'SETTINGS',
        'TIMELINE'],
    // 'SEU':
    //     ['MODULE'],
};
var loadController = function(controllerName) {
  return ["$q","$rootScope", function($q,$rootScope) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      require([controllerName], function() {
                            deferred.resolve();
                            $rootScope.$apply();
                             });
      return deferred.promise;
  }];
       }

_.each(menu,function(value,key){
    var module = baseDirectories + key + '/' + key ;
    $stateProvider.state('/' + key,{
        url: '/' + key,
        templateUrl : module + '.html',
        controller: key,
        resolve : loadController(module),
    });    
})
```

And I'm getting the error below :

> Argument 'SUSR' is not aNaNunction, got undefined

Could you please tell me where the problem is?
thanks and regards.

Comment: The view of my controller is loaded correctly but not the controller...

Comment: Some news: the js file of my controller is loaded but I have a problem to instantiate the controllers...

Comment: I have created a plunk to reproduce my problem https://plnkr.co/edit/nlfoMoEF5FVm2FnsufYG?p=preview
Does anyone can help me?